# Purpose of list.html and section.html in Hugo

Tags: hugo

I tried to find what these files are used for, but couldn't find anything.

I'm making a theme for Hugo and wanted to know they are required.

Also if they are required what is their purpose?

The files I'm asking about:

```
themes\[THEME]\_default\list.html
```

and

```
themes\[THEME]\_default\section.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the information that I was searched for, and probably should've waited before asking, but since I already asked let me answer it for the other people.

`list.html` is used by Hugo to generate a page that displays a list of the pages inside the `content` folder. It is not required for Hugo to work, but another page would have to replace it. Most commonly this would be `index.html` in the `layouts` folder.

`section.html` I'm still not really sure what this is used for, but it is not required. There is a way to make a separate `list.html` files for a specific folders in the `contents` folder, but I still haven't checked out all the details about this.

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpOnyRlyS-liKL5ReHDcj4G3) tutorials on YouTube by Mike Dane which may be useful although they are pretty old.